# while querying how to get one column with order by on another column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL I want to get one column in order by another column

e.g.

```
X Y
ab 4
cd 2
ef 3
gh 1
```

I want column A with order of 2nd

```
o/p
X
gh
cd
ef
ab
```

Another thing:
I had basically view view1 from another source

```
select distinct X, Y, Z
from table 
order by Y
```

So I am querying on this view

```
select X from view1 where z='(:value)'
```

So does it gurantee it will be in order of y?
Or how can I make it in order of y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply looking for `order by`?

```
select x
from t
order by y;
```

If so, this is very basic SQL and you should study up on the basics if you are attempting to use the language.

Comment: thank you for reply @Gordon Linoff can you please help me with second question like can I get values in sorted order if I not include order by while select query but view is sorted on y.

Comment: @RiddhiPatel . . . Results are only guaranteed to be sorted if you order them in the outermost query.  Ordering in a view -- if your database allows that -- does not guarantee final result ordering.